# Cygwin + Linux NDK on Windows

Tags: linux, eclipse-plugin, android-ndk, cygwin

I think this sounds strange but it's my situation now.

I have an Android JNI project on Eclipse (Windows), but after my friend 's configuration in his Eclipse on Ubuntu, now the auto-build plugin on my Eclipse couldn't work (It raise the error: ...ld.exe: can not find -l):

```
**** Build of configuration Default for project TachoPro ****
ndk-build.cmd all 
SharedLibrary  : libtachometer_core.so
E:/Android/android-ndk-r8b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -ltachometer_core_armv7_a_cortex_a9
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libtachometer_core.so] Error 1
**** Build Finished ****
```

He said that I must download the NDK for Linux then use Cygwin to build. But another error (seems more complex than before) arrives:
http://www.mediafire.com/view/?o0nthcn3hn0b0ix

If you has been through this, please give me some advices... >"<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're working on Windows, you have to use the Windows version of the Android NDK, not the Linux.
If you took a configuration file from your friend which points to a linux executable, you need to fix that. only that.
can you post the configuration file he gave you ?

Comment: Yeah... (maybe the Linux Eclipse did that).

Comment: Here 's the link of all files (that I think are "config-files") in my project (I keep the directory-tree but deleted the source codes, of course) http://www.mediafire.com/?ol73s8um49ft1wb >"<

Comment: We 've found the real problem - it is our svn server. It ignored those ".a" libs when commit. Thank you all for your replies ^^

Answer (score 0):

read about how to develop with Android and with the NDK, **you don't need Cygwin** to develop with the NDK under Windows, also **Cygwin it's not meant to be an environment for developers** ( it's written crystal clear in the project homepage ! ).

I don't know what you 2 are doing but surely it's not Android related or a good use of both Cygwin or Android tools.